# PHPExcel alters rounding behavior on my server - Seeking suggestions for debugging

Tags: php, floating-point, phpexcel, rounding

I have a strange bug on my server where instantiating a PHPExcel object causes identical rounding operations to return different results. I'm seeking ideas how I can debug this so that I can target an upgrade path to resolve the issue. Searching the PHP changelogs does not mention the issue.

Consider the following code:

```
include  'vendor/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';

$old = round(0.6164,4);

$excel = new \PHPExcel();

$new = round(0.6164,4);
debug_zval_dump($old, $new);
```

Here is the output on my server (64bit Linux):

```
$php -v
PHP 5.4.11 (cli) (built: Jan 16 2013 16:51:38)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
$ php test.php
string(6) "0.6164" refcount(2)
string(18) "0.6163999999999999" refcount(2)
```

Which i cannot reproduce on my local machine (Win64):

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.4.11 (cli) (built: Jan 16 2013 20:26:43)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
$ php test.php
string(6) "0.6164" refcount(2)
string(6) "0.6164" refcount(2)
```

I'm very confused by this behavior as such low level details should be abstracted away, right? Can someone familiar with PHP's internals comment on what may be going on here?

Comment: You're doing string->float->string conversions. you ARE going to lose precision, since a string can be exactly accurate, and float is essentially never exactly accurate. This has nothing to do with PHP, or PHPExcel, and everything to do with how floating point numbers act in the "real world".

Comment: Welcome to the world of floating point numbers. This is standard behavior pretty much everywhere.

Comment: I'm not being sarcastic and I'm not kidding either. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php Check out the giant red warning box for starters. This isn't an issue for just php either. Pretty much all programming languages have the same issue.

Comment: Can you explain why including a seemingly unrelated object (a PHPExcel instance) results in different behavior for the second round operation across different platforms?

Comment: I would just be guessing at something like lag introduced from including a large script. Nothing phpExcel specific. You would probably have better results using something like sprintf like `sprintf('%.4f', $float)` when converting to string. And the precision setting can differ between different platforms/system based on 32 or 64 bit as well as it is documented. From the manual: `The size of a float is platform-dependent`.

Comment: Jon - PHP excel was changing the precision (per mark) of displayed floats so it was altering the (string) casting behavior. Using your sprintf standardizes this behavior by forcing me to specify decimals. My mistake was using round then (string) instead of simply sprintf. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHPExcel Calculation Engine modified the `precision` setting from php.ini, setting it to 12 on 32-bit systems, 16 on 64-bit systems if it's defined as a lower value.

This setting is restored when the PHPExcel object is unset

Comment: Thank you that explains it.